# React Komposer + Container Pattern + Data Input

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm now working with react-komposer and the container/component pattern, but it's left me wondering how to handle data input.

For example, an `AddVehicleForm` component has a container that pre-populates some fields with data from the database. With the standard React Komposer examples, this makes sense:

```
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { Vehicles } from '../../collections/vehicles.js';
import AddVehicleForm from '../components/AddVehicleForm.jsx';

const composer = ( props, onData ) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe( 'vehicles' );

  if ( subscription.ready() ) {
    const curVehicles = Vehicles.find().fetch();
    onData( null, { curVehicles } );
  }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker( composer )( AddVehicleForm );
```

But, to keep the component truly unreliant on it's data source, you would also need to pass it a `handleSubmit()` function to submit to the database, would you not? Where would you put this function?

Alternatively, I can see how it wouldn't be hard to solve using TrackerReact. But, as React Komposer is so widely adopted, what's the common way to handle this case?

**EDIT:**

Just throwing out an idea, but is there any reason not to create a container component with submit handling methods and then wrap that with the composer function? Something akin to this:

```
import {composeWithTracker} from 'react-komposer';
import ClassroomDashboard from '/imports/components/classroomDashboard/ClassroomDashboard.jsx';


class ClassroomDashboardContainer extends React.Component {

    onSubmitHandle(e) {
        // check form data and submit to DB
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ClassroomDashboard {...this.props} onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)} />
        )
    }
}

function composerFunction(props, onData) {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('classroom');

    if (handle.ready()) {
        const classroom = Classrooms.findOne(props.params.id);
        onData(null, {classroom});
    };
};

export default composeWithTracker(composerFunction)(ClassroomDashboardContainer);
```

Comment: Take a look at the Mantra architecture as an example of how handler functions are passed to components (composition with actions).

Comment: Checked it out, seems pretty robust. But, the whole actions layer adds a lot of complexity to my simple app. I think I'd rather something less involved. Thank you for the comment.